# Align section, subsection and paragraph number in left margin in left in report

Tags: align, leftmargin

I want to align section, subsection and paragraph number in left margin in left.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}\makeatletter
....
\renewcommand\paragraph{
    \@startsection {paragraph}               % name
    {4}                                      % level
    {\z@}                                    % indent 
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}       % before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}                      % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}        % style
  }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{
    \@startsection {subparagraph}            % name
    {5}                                      % level
    {\z@}                                    % indent 
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}       % before skip
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}                     % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}        % style
  }

\def\@seccntformat#1{\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{6pt}}}

\makeatother
```

I obtain this

[image: I obtain this]

BUT I want align number in the left like this:

3-------text

3.1-----text

3.1.2---text

how can i do that without edit my custom paragraph?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I don't have an answer, but something you need to think about.  Will any of these sectional numbers ever reach two digits or even more?  That will have to be taken into consideration when designing your changed format.

Comment: that's exactly why I want them aligned to the left. Aligning them to the right is even more chaotic

Answer (score 0):

The number of the sectional unit (for `\section`, `\subsection` and lower) within the title is set via `\@seccntformat`. You've defined that to be a zero-width box that is `r`ight-aligned and has a `6pt` space at the end through

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{6pt}}}
```

This effectively sets the numbers in the margin. To get the format you're after if you change your definition to this

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3cm][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{6pt}}}
```

and adjust the value of `3cm` accordingly. Higher values will push it further into the margin, and smaller values will bring it closer to the margin. You may consider dropping the `\hspace{6pt}` element altogether with a suitable choice of `3cm`. Choosing a non-font-related size is better as the fonts change for each sectional units.

Comment: thank you so much. I only changed it like this \ def \ @ seccntformat # 1 {\ makebox [0pt] [r] {\ makebox [2cm] [l] {\ csname the # 1 \ endcsname}}}. Thanks again